# How to draw a second line on this specific way to plot?

Tags: python

I normally plot graphs in a completely different way, which doesn't work here. Here, the y data is defined by set_ydata. So, I don't see a way to have a second graph in the same plot. Does someone have an idea how to achieve it here?

I tried

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,
NavigationToolbar2Tk)
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import serial

stroke=30
conrod=75
bore=40

def update_plot():
    y = 59 * np.random.rand(50)
    lines[0].set_ydata(array_pressure_1)
    canvas.draw()    
    window.after(25, update_plot)  # run again after 25ms (1000ms/25ms = 40 FPS (frames per second))
    
def main():
    global window
    global canvas
    global lines
    
    #below has to be fiddled with for axis scale
    x = np.linspace(0, stroke, 50)
    y = 100 * np.random.rand(50)

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title('Plotting in Tkinter')
    window.geometry("500x500")

    #The canvas the figure is drawn on:
    fig = Figure(figsize = (4, 4), dpi = 100)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    lines = plot1.plot(x, y)

    window.after(25, update_plot)  # run first time after 25ms
    update_plot()  # run first time at once

    window.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly adapted your code to include new lines... and I've introduced the concept of [blitting](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html) which will greatly speed up your animations!
(I also re-named `plot1` to `ax` which is the commonly used name for matplotlib axes)

The general concept is the following:

- a call to `ax.plot()` will return a set with 1 new artist
  (to directly unpack it use something like `l, = ax.plot()`)
- now simply create as much lines as you need,
  put them in some container (list, dict etc.)
  and then use `l.set_xdata()`, `l.set_color()` etc. to update the artist
- to avoid re-drawing the whole image all the time, use blitting (e.g. cache the background and only re-draw animated artists on top)

here's a working example with multiple lines:

[image]

```py
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,
NavigationToolbar2Tk)
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# import serial

stroke=30
conrod=75
bore=40

lines = []

def update_plot():
    global lines
    global ax
    global bg
    
    y = 59 * np.random.rand(50)
    
    # update the lines
    lines[0].set_ydata(y)
    lines[1].set_ydata(y + np.random.normal(5,10))
    lines[2].set_ydata(y - np.random.normal(5,10))

    # restore the background
    canvas.restore_region(bg)

    # re-draw only the artists that have changed
    for l in lines:
        ax.draw_artist(l)
               
    # efficiently re-draw the image using "blitting"
    canvas.blit(ax.bbox)

    window.after(25, update_plot)  # run again after 25ms (1000ms/25ms = 40 FPS (frames per second))
    
def main():
    global window
    global canvas
    global lines
    global ax
    global bg
    
    #below has to be fiddled with for axis scale
    x = np.linspace(0, stroke, 50)
    y = 100 * np.random.rand(50)

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title('Plotting in Tkinter')
    window.geometry("500x500")

    #The canvas the figure is drawn on:
    fig = Figure(figsize = (4, 4), dpi = 100)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()


    # add a new axes
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_ylim(-20,100)
    
    # plot a static line on the background
    static_l1 = ax.plot(x, y/2, c="r", lw=4)

    # draw everything that goes on the background
    canvas.draw()

    # cache the background
    bg = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)

    # add some lines (will be updated later)
    l1, = ax.plot(x, y)
    lines.append(l1)
    
    l2, = ax.plot(x, y)
    lines.append(l2)
    
    l3, = ax.plot(x, y)
    lines.append(l3)

    # set dynamically updated lines to "animated" 
    # (e.g. exclude them from ordinary draw-events)
    for l in lines:
        l.set_animated(True)

    window.after(25, update_plot)  # run first time after 25ms
    update_plot()  # run first time at once

    window.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I never knew about such a method of reducing processing time. I only know them from missile tracking software.